# Animation between two activities

Tags: android, animation, transition, slide

I'm working on a game and I am stuck right now.
The goal here is to create an animation between two menus which are also activities. But it is not as simple as it sounds now. If the user presses a button, two doors form left and right should slide in and cover the menu. After touching in the center, they should slide back out and reveal the new menu. Thats why i can't use a standard transition animation. 
Help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For **Right to left** animation use this animation. your menu will get hidden by this :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="50%p"
         android:toXDelta="0"
         android:interpolator="@android:anim/anticipate_overshoot_interpolator"
          android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

Just copy this lines and save as a xml file in anim folder.

For **Left to right**  use the following lines:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-50%p"
         android:toXDelta="0"
         android:interpolator="@android:anim/anticipate_overshoot_interpolator"
          android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

Copy and save with another name in the anim folder.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that is not working properly.
there are two doors sliding in from left and right at the same time, covering the "old" menu/activity and while opening up again, revealing the new menu/activity.